# Continuous function defined in spheres

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, continuity, compactness

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Show that $\phi:[0,+\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined as $\phi(r)=\sup_{||x||=r}\{f(x)\}$ is continuous. I'm aware of [$f\colon \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ continuous, $\phi (r) = \sup_{|x| =r} f(x)$ is continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1562704/f-colon-mathbbrn-rightarrow-mathbbr-continuous-phi-r-sup-x), but I would like a different proof, and besides I believe the first answer has a mistake and the second is incomplete.

My attempt:
By compactness of $\{||x||=r\}$, $\phi$ is clearly well defined. Let $r\in (0,+\infty),\,\epsilon>0$.

Then there exists $x_r\in \mathbb{R},||x_r||=r, \phi(r)=\sup_{||x||=r}\{f(x)\}=f(x_r)$. So there exists $\delta_0>0$ such that $|f(x_r)-f(x)|<\epsilon$. Now, if we take $\delta = \delta_0$, then for $\forall l, |l-r|<\delta$, let $x_l$ be such that $\phi(l)=f(x_l)$ and take $x = \frac{l}{r}x_r$. Then clearly $||x-x_r|| = |l-r|<\delta_0$, so $|f(x_r)-f(x)|<\epsilon$.

Assume $f(x_r)\geq f(x_l)$. Then $f(x_r)\geq f(x_l)\geq f(x)$, so $|f(x_r)-f(x_l)|<\epsilon$

My problem is if  $f(x_r)< f(x_l)$, any tips?

Comment: What do you think is incomplete about Hagen von Eitzen's answer?

Comment: @EricWofsey I don't see why $\phi(r_n)>\frac{f(\hat x)+f(y)}2$. Also, I believe there's a mistake here: $\phi(r_n)=f(y_n)\to f(y)$, it should be $\phi(r_n)=f(x_n)\to f(y)$

Comment: There is some $x$ with $|x|=r_n$ such that $f(x)>\frac{f(\hat{x})+f(y)}{2}$ (namely any $x$ sufficiently close to $\hat{x}$), and therefore $\phi(r_n)>\frac{f(\hat{x})+f(y)}{2}$ by definition of $\phi$.

Comment: Ah I see now. I was still hoping to find a a proof using $\epsilon-\delta$, but perhaps it's too complicated